# Discrete symmetries of General relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, discrete

What are the discrete symmetries of General Relativity? Is it invariant under CP, C, P,T or all?

Comment: How would you define C, P, and T in the context of GR?

Comment: Pure GR with no matter, or GR + the standard model?

Comment: @Andrew GR coupled to matter.

Comment: @TimRias. Am not sure. I am currently studying an introduction to particle physics where the author mentions the discrete symmetries of the standard model. I am wondering if GR also has discrete symmetries such as Charge conjugation, Parity and Time Reversal. If not, I'd also like to know why.

Comment: Since C, P, and T are not symmetries of the standard model, they won't be symmetries of GR coupled to the standard model (even after addressing @TimRias's point).

Comment: Perhaps a better way to phrase the question is whether the discrete transformations which reduce to C,P,T in the flat spacetime limit have sensible extensions to strongly curved geometries, and then separately whether GR is symmetric under those transformations. Note that Newtonian gravity is symmetric under P and T, so one would expect a Lorentz-invariant extension to also be symmetric under C.